# Property of the norm of an ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

In Stewart/Tall's book on ANT they authors claim that if $ 0 \ne \mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{O}_K$ the ring of integers of a number field $K$, then $N(\mathfrak{a}) \in \mathfrak{a}$. The proof they give is unclear to me, can someone please explain this?

Comment: Hm... that makes immediate sense. But for some reason the authors proved this via an awkward argument involving containment in $\mathfrak{O}$. Was there a benefit to doing this?

Comment: What definition is used for the norm of an ideal?

Comment: It is defined as the order of the quotient ring but there are results relating it to the determinant of the change of basis matrix.

Comment: The definition I know  is that it is the determinant of a basis of the $\mathbf Z$-module $\mathfrak a$ w.r.t. a basis of $\mathfrak O_K$, and $N(\mathfrak a)=\lvert\mathfrak O_K/\mathfrak a\rvert$  is a theorem.

Comment: The first comment by Bernard is not a proof. A proper ideal will not contain all integers. The ring $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak a$ has order ${\rm N}(\mathfrak a)$, so by viewing this ring just as an additive group we get by Lagrange's theorem that ${\rm N}(\mathfrak a)x \in \mathfrak a$ for all $x$ in $\mathcal O_K$. Now take $x = 1$.